# Invoke special method before any method of my class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

Is there a special method that when I call any class's method, it will be invoked?

Below there's an example that explains my problem:

```
class Foo{
   public function bar(){
      echo 'foo::bar';
   }

   public function before(){
      echo 'before any methods';
   }

   public function after(){
      echo 'after any methods';
   }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```

The output should be:

```
 /*
    Output:
    before any methods
    foo::bar
    after any methods
*/
```

Comment: no there nothing as such however there are 2 magic methods `__call()` and `__callStatic()` which are called when a non accessible methods are called or in other words the methods does not exit in a class.

Comment: No, you have to call this method from within each other method of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

personally i don´t like this solution, but you are able to use the magic method **__call**:

```
/**
 * @method bar
 */
class Foo{

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $myfunc = '_'.$name;
        $this->before();
        if (method_exists($this,$myfunc)) {
            $this->$myfunc();
        }
        $this->after();
    }

    public function _bar(){
        echo 'foo::bar';
    }

    public function before(){
        echo 'before any methods';
    }

    public function after(){
        echo 'after any methods';
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```

Comment: This is more of a hack, than anything. This will execute the preceding and succeeding functions no matter if the method exists or not, however.

Comment: @BrandonWhite: i think people are clever enough to put before() and after() inside the method_exists ;-))

Comment: Just a reminder: `__call` is only invoked when the actual called method does not exists. I arrived at this SO Link when trying to figure out whether `__call` was invoked **before** or **after** the actual method, but if the method actually exists, it doesnt' get invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The only way to invoke these methods would be to call them within each individual method.

```
class Foo{
   public function bar(){
      $this->before();
      echo 'foo::bar';
      $this->after();
   }

   public function before(){
      echo 'before any methods';
   }

   public function after(){
      echo 'after any methods';
   }
}
```

This would output as expected:

```
/*
before any methods
foo::bar
after any methods
*/
```